# Which is better, double negation or bitshift?

Tags: c, performance, bit-manipulation, return-value, bitwise-and

I need a boolean-type function which determines if a bit, in a variable's bit representation, is set or not.

So if the fourth bit of `foo` is what I want to inspect, I could make the function return

```
!!(foo & 0x8)  //0x8 = 1000b
```

or

```
(foo & 0x8) >> 3
```

to get either 0 or 1.

Which one is more desirable in terms of performance or portability? I'm working on a small embedded system so a little but detectable cost difference still matters.

Comment: Only after you've determined the criticality of this code as a central hotspot, compile both to optimized platform asm,  then dissect the resulting instructions and determine which uses fewer clocks per the embedded architecture (cpu+bus). Note the latter is *worthless* until you've concretely determine its necessity by the former.

Comment: _I need a boolean-type function which determines if a bit, in a variable's bit representation, is set or not._ Assuming there's not much else apart from this snippet in the function, if your function returns `_Bool` the 0/1 change should happen automatically when you return it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution

```
return (foo & 0x8) >> 3;
```

is the worst. If for example the magic constant `0x8` will be changed then you also need to change the magic constant `3`. And moreover it can occur such a way that applying the operator >> will be impossible for example when you need to check more than one bit.

If you want to return either 1 (logical true) or 0 (logical false) I think that it will look more clear if to write

```
return (foo & 0x8) != 0;
```

or

```
return (foo & 0x8) == 0x8;
```

For example if instead of the magic constant 0x8 you will use a named constant (or variable) as for example MASK then this return statement

```
return ( foo & MASK ) == MASK;
```

will not depend on the value of MASK.

Pay attention to that these two return statements

```
return (foo & MASK) != 0;
```

and

```
return ( foo & MASK ) == MASK;
```

are not equivalent. The first return statement means that at least one bit is set in the variable `foo` while the second return statement means that exactly all bits corresponding to bits in MASK are set.

If the return type of the function is `_Bool` (or `bool` defined in `<stdbool.h>`) and you need to check whether at least one bit is set according to the bit mask then you can just write

```
return foo & MASK;
```

Comment: What about `(foo >> BITNUM) & 1`?

Comment: @Vilx- As I mentioned in my answer if you need to check more than one bit then this will not work. Moreover this expression is not equivalent to your original expression because the value of a bit mask and the value used in the shift expression can be different,

Comment: I those cases, yes. But I get the feeling that the asker just wants to test a single bit.

Comment: @Vilx- If he needs to test one bit then it is enough to make the return type _Bool without any shifting.

Comment: But does he know that?

Comment: @Vilx- I provided the required information in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Which one is more desirable in terms of performance or portability?

For performance, it all depends on how your compiler optimizes the functions. For example, compiling these two functions:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t not_not(uint32_t foo)
{
    return !!(foo & 0x8);
}

uint32_t bit_shift(uint32_t foo)
{
    return (foo & 0x8) >> 3;
}
```

Compile to the exact same assembly with x64 GCC 11.1 `-O3` ([link](https://godbolt.org/z/Ed5xs7czG)):

```
not_not:
        mov     eax, edi
        shr     eax, 3
        and     eax, 1
        ret
bit_shift:
        mov     eax, edi
        shr     eax, 3
        and     eax, 1
        ret
```

So you should check the assembly generated by whatever compiler you're using at your preferred optimization level to see if any one of them is faster than the other.

As for portability, considering that in some case you may have to change the bitmask to some other value, `!!` might be the safer option since changing the bitmask won't force you to change the shift amount as well. You could also use the suggestions Vlad from Moscow suggested.

Comment: You shouldn't be using signed types for bit manipulations. And if you drop `int` for `uint32_t` I bet the machine code will also turn 100% equivalent.

Comment: @Lundin you're right, edited to change the type.

Answer (score 0):

Both will generate a very similar code so performance-wise it is exactly (or almost exactly) the same.

Double negation was used by the programmers for many years and (IMO) it clearly indicates the programmer intentions. If you have the second shift you need to spend a bit more time reading the code. It is also more error-prone as humans make stupid mistakes (typos for example). Can you easily tell me if `(x & 0x8000000000000) >> 52` is correct or not without consideration?

`(x & 0x1000000000000) >> 48)` is not as clear as `!!(x & 0x1000000000000)`

Answer (score 0):

Performance-wise there won't be much difference if any. Readability-wise, you should use neither form.

> ... if the fourth bit of foo is what I want to inspect...

...then you should be using the fourth bit as input. Bit 3 being the fourth bit since bits are counted from 0 and upwards:

```
uint32_t n = 3;
if(foo & (1u << n))
```

This is by far the most common way to mask bits in C. If you need the value 1 or 0, then you could use `!!` or just `_Bool b = foo & (1u << n);`.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about the performance (benchmark maybe?), but here are two more ideas:

```
(x >> BITNUM) & 1
```

This uses one bit shift and one binary AND. As a bonus, you specify the NUMBER of the bit you want to see, and no other magical constants. Pretty easy to use.

```
(x & MASK) != 0
```

This uses one binary AND and a comparison with zero. AFAIK comparing with zero is a special operation on most processors, so it should be cheap. It's even possible that this result is automatically calculated by the processor as a byproduct of the binary AND and stored in a CPU flag. If so, then the comparison with zero might get optimized out entirely leaving you with just one bitwise AND (depends on the CPU, compiler and the rest of your code though).

Last but not least, if you're just using this for IF statements then maybe you don't really need to coerce it to 1 and 0? I mean, in C anything non-0 is truthy, so this:

```
if (x & MASK)
```

would work just fine and produce optimal code.